# cubic and quadratic graphs?

Tags: python, graph, pygame, quadratic, cubic

I am trying to make a pygame program that 'sketches' cubic and quadratic graphs.
my code is below. but every time i try running the code i get this error.

```
y = 250 - ((A(x)**B)+(C(x)**D)+(E(x))+c)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I don't really know what it means or how to solve it.

sorry if i'm being a pain posting all of my code, i just needed to see if there are any other problems with the code

```
import pygame,sys,time,random
A =1
B =2
C =5
D =1
E =7
c =5
line = (0,0,0)
x = 0.0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
screen.fill((255,255,255))
draw = True
start = True
count = 0
while start:
    pygame.draw.line(screen,(0,0,0),(250,0),(250,500))
    pygame.draw.line(screen,(0,0,0),(0,250),(500,250))
    while x <=500:
        y = 250 - ((A(x)**B)+(C(x)**D)+(E(x))+c)
        pos = (((x)+250),y)
        pygame.draw.line(screen,(line),(pos),(pos))
        pygame.display.update()
        x +=1
       for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit();sys.quit();

        again = raw_input('again? y/n')
        if again == 'y' or again == 'yes':
            start = True
            screen.fill(255,255,255)
            x = 0.0
        elif again == 'n' or again == 'no':
            start = False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as the error says, `int` object is not callable.

You need to do

```
y = 250 - ((A*(x)**B)+(C*(x**D))+(E*(x))+c)
```

`2(5)` does not mean `2*5` in python & many other programming languages. You need to specify the multiplication between them.

As for the latter part of the error statement, `A(x)` means you are *calling* function `A` with the argument(s) `x`.